# how to enable in chrome icedtea7 java plugin instead of icedtea6?

Tags: java, google-chrome, plugins, openjdk, icedtea

My chrome browser in ubuntu 12.04 uses iced6 plugin. Test http://java.com/en/download/testjava.jsp shows java6, but via update-alternatives I switched java/javac to using openjdk-java7

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to manually update a symlink in: /opt/google/chrome/plugins/

Comment: Aha... how would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Just open a terminal and enter

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

Now you see different choices and can select by entering the right number. You can also do the same with `javac`, `javadoc` and others. See `update-alternatives --display | grep java` for a list of all Java related entries.